# How to determine which component is for a React child?

Tags: reactjs

When one component have multiple children, can i iterate over the children, and determine if it is an instance of some component ? Like this:

```
React.Children.forEach(function(child) {
    if(child instanceOf SomeComponent) {
        ...do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me using React 0.14 (I believe will also work for 0.13):

```
React.Children.forEach(function(child) {
  if(child.type === SomeComponent) {
    ...do something
  }
}
```